# Django objects.update_or_create

Tags: python, django, api, templates

i have a periodic_task running in celery that query for latest Cryptocurrency prices but for some reason, each time a want to display the data i dont get updated records i just get new ones and the old records are keep for some reason.

tasks.py

```
@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='*/1')), name="Update Crypto rate(s)", ignore_result=True)
def get_exchange_rate():
    api_url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"
    try:
        exchange_rates = requests.get(api_url).json()
        for exchange_rate in exchange_rates:
            CryptoPrices.objects.update_or_create(key=exchange_rate['id'],
                                                  symbol=exchange_rate['symbol'],
                                                  market_cap_usd=round(float(exchange_rate['market_cap_usd']), 3),
                                                  volume_usd_24h=round(float(exchange_rate['24h_volume_usd']), 3),
                                                  defaults={'value': round(float(exchange_rate['price_usd']), 3)}
                                                  )
        logger.info("Crypto exchange rate(s) updated successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

models.py

```
class CryptoPrices(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    volume_usd_24h = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    market_cap_usd = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

views.py

```
def crypto_ticker(request):
        list_prices = CryptoPrices.objects.get_queryset().order_by('pk')
        paginator = Paginator(list_prices, 100)  # Show 100 prices per page
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        price = paginator.get_page(page)
        return render(request, 'crypto_ticker.html', {'price': price})
```

template.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load readmore %}

{% block breadcrumbs %}
    {{ block.super }} » <a href="{% url 'post_list' %}">Posts </a> »
    <a href="{% url 'crypto_ticker' %}">Crypto ticker</a>
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Crypto ticker</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h1 class="center">Crypto ticker</h1>
    <hr class="hr-style">
    <div class="center">
        <h4>{{ prices }} Here you can find all frequently asked questions <br>
            if you still have still have any open points, please contact the <a href="#">support</a>.</h4>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="paginator">
        <span>
         {% if price.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; First <a> |</a></a>
            <a href="?page={{ price.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        {% if price.has_next %}
            <span> Crypto prices - Page {{ price.number }} of {{ price.paginator.num_pages }}.</span>
            <a href="?page={{ price.next_page_number }}">Next<a> |</a></a>
            <a href="?page={{ price.paginator.num_pages }}">Last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
       </span>
   </div>
    <table class="table centercontentfloat class-three-box">
        <thead>
            <tr style="font-size: small">
                <th>Ranking</th>
                <th>Symbol</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Market Cap (USD)</th>
                <th>24 hrs. Volume (USD)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for price in price %}
            <tr style="font-size: small">
                <td>{{ price.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ price.symbol }}</td>
                <td>{{ price.key }}</td>
                <td>{{ price.value }} $</td>
                <td style="font-size: small">{{ price.market_cap_usd }} $</td>
                <td style="font-size: small">{{ price.volume_usd_24h }} $</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="paginator">
        <span>
            {% if price.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; First <a> |</a></a>
            <a href="?page={{ price.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        {% if price.has_next %}
            <span> Crypto prices - Page {{ price.number }} of {{ price.paginator.num_pages }}.</span>
            <a href="?page={{ price.next_page_number }}">Next<a> |</a></a>
            <a href="?page={{ price.paginator.num_pages }}">Last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
       </span>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Is there any notable reason why the records i grab from the coinmarketcap api is getting saved/ displayed twice?

if i go trough the pages i get back something like this:

> Crypto prices - Page 1 of 21. Next | Last »
>   Ranking   Symbol  Name    Price   Market Cap (USD)    24 hrs. Volume (USD)
>   1 BTC bitcoin 3795.6465 $ 66594617840.0 $ 8296474984.64 $
>   2 ETH ethereum    143.9996 $  15106822040.0 $ 5043716023.22 $

and on the second page:

> « First | Previous Crypto prices - Page 2 of 22. Next | Last »
>   Ranking   Symbol  Name    Price   Market Cap (USD)    24 hrs. Volume (USD)
>   101   BTC bitcoin 3798.3016 $ 66641201438.0 $ 8304474934.43 $
>   102   ETH ethereum    144.0825 $  15115524904.0 $ 5048205218.98 $

and i dont expect that BTC is also at the second page, only once at the first page?!?

It really seems if i go trough the pages, that the records dont get updated, they will get saved one after another after each periodic_task run

Kind regards

Comment: You use 4 fields to get the object to update. That is what's leading to creating new objects, because those fields have a different value when the crontab executes and they cannot be updated since they are used to identify the object to update. Simple answer: `CryptoPrices.objects.update_or_create(symbol=exchange_rate['symbol'], defaults={all you want to update comes here})`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're using all the fields in the query for existing instances. You need to just use the unique ones there, and the rest in the `defaults` dict.

```
CryptoPrices.objects.update_or_create(
   key=exchange_rate['id'],
   symbol=exchange_rate['symbol'],
   defaults={             
       "market_cap_usd": round(float(exchange_rate['market_cap_usd']), 3),
       "volume_usd_24h": round(float(exchange_rate['24h_volume_usd']), 3),
       "value": round(float(exchange_rate['price_usd']), 3)
    })
```

Answer (score 20):

You're misinterpreting how `update_or_create` works. This is what the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) say:

> The `update_or_create` method tries to fetch an object from database
>   based on the given `kwargs`. If a match is found, it updates the fields
>   passed in the `defaults` dictionary.

So in `kwargs` you only pass the values that you need to get a match, not the updates. Probably passing `id` or `symbol` should be the only `kwargs` you need. All the parameters you want to update need to be passed to `defaults`.

```
CryptoPrices.objects.update_or_create(
    key=exchange_rate['id'],
    symbol=exchange_rate['symbol'],
    defaults=dict(
        market_cap_usd=round(float(exchange_rate['market_cap_usd']), 3),
        volume_usd_24h=round(float(exchange_rate['24h_volume_usd']), 3),
        value= round(float(exchange_rate['price_usd']), 3))
)
```