# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auctions_bids.item_id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I building the auctions website and have this problem:

UNIQUE constraint failed: auctions_bids.item_id

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE
from django.db.models.fields import EmailField, NOT_PROVIDED


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Listings(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    price = models.FloatField()
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    listed_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}" #{self.description} {self.price} {self.image_url} {self.category}"


class Bids(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Listings, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bid = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    user_bid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.item} {self.bid} {self.user_bid}"
```

views.py

```
def placebid(request, id_product):
    if request.method == "POST":
        item_list = Listings.objects.get(pk=id_product)
        bid = request.POST['bid']
        user = request.user
        Bids.objects.update_or_create(item=item_list, bid=bid, user_bid=user)
        return redirect(reverse("listings", args=(id,)))
```

[image]

When I try to update the new bid, this appears the above error, the only way to delete the old object and create a new object, I want to update the new bid if the object exists and create if the object doesn't exist by using `update_or_create`

I think I had wrong in setting parameter item values of the Bids model, but I don't know how to fix them! Any advice for me, Thanks so much !!!

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54749547/7865368

Comment: use `update_or_create` like this `Bids.objects.update_or_create(item=item_list, user_bid=user, defaults=dict({bid=bid}))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are filtering on the `bid` and `user_bid` as well. This thus means that it will only *update* if the `item`, `bid` and `userbid` are the same. But likely you want to update from the moment `item` is the same, so you should use the **`defaults=…`** parameter of the [**`.update_or_create(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update_or_create):

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def placebid(request, id_product):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        bid = request.POST['bid']
        user = request.user
        Bids.objects.update_or_create(
            item_id=id_product
            defaults={'bid': bid, 'user_bid': user}
        )
        return redirect('listings', id)
```

Django will thus check if it can find a `Bids` object for which `item_id` is `id_product`. If it can, it will update `bid` and `user_bid` as specified in the `defaults`, otherwise it will *create* a `Bids` object with these defaults.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Bid` instead of <s>`Bids`</s>.